# Format output to a specific line length

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, text

So I have some output that has very long lines, and I want to have it formatted to lines no more than 80 columns wide, but I don't want to split words because they are in the column limit.

I tried

```
sed 's/.\{80\}/&\n/g'
```

but has the problem of splitting words and making some lines begin with a space.

I managed to do it with Vim, setting `textwidth` to 80, going to the beginnig of the file and executing `gqG` to format the text. But ¡ would rather do it with `sed`, `awk` or something similar to include it in a script.

Comment: Why don't you use `fmt`?

Comment: @Celada Because I didn't know of its existence :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `fmt` instead:

```
fmt --width=80 file
```

From `man fmt`:

```
-w, --width=WIDTH
              maximum line width (default of 75 columns)
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `fold` as follows:

```
fold -s -w80 file
```

This will only split at whitespace (`-s`), using a line width of 80 characters (`-w80`). So it does exactly the same as the `fmt` solutions, but it also allows to break at *any* character when omitting the `-s` option.

Comment: This is the best answer considering `fmt` merges separate lines by eating new lines.

Answer (score 3):

Below mentioned solution might help:

> cat file_name.txt | fmt -w 80 > reduced_file_name.txt

fmt - simple optimal text formatter.

Comment: Use less of cat: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat